# How can I update a MySQL table with GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

How can I use the Group_Concat command to update a table?

Basically, I want to turn this:

```
SET_1 | SET_2
4       12
4       13
5       12
5       13
```

Into this:

```
SET_1 | SET_2
4       12, 13
5       12, 13
```

Comment: please read first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and create a new table and delete the old one

Comment: updating on the current table, or inserting them into a new table with this style? Btw, doesn't `set_2` column have numeric data type ?

Comment: Be absolutely sure why you need to do this. Storing CSV data in a single column can lead to a world of hurt later.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Updating your current table might be complicated. It is better to create a new table, select the data using `group_concat` and insert it to your new table. And make sure the `set_2` column is not an integer or else you'll get an error.

```
INSERT INTO yournewtable(col1, col2) SELECT set_1, GROUP_CONCAT(set_2) FROM currenttable GROUP BY set_1
```